# How to generate random ISO date for every document in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using this code in MongoDB aggregation:

```
{
  date: ISODate()
}
```

It's generating current date in ISO format for every document.

How can I generate random ISO date for every document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`$rand`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/) and multiply the current UNIX timestamp with it:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "date": {
      $toDate: {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $rand: {}
          },
          {
            $subtract: [
              new Date(),
              new Date("1970-01-01")
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wH83_Y5jg3y) to playground

Answer (score 0):

The mongoDB docs on [Date() / ISODate()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/) say

> You can specify a particular date by passing an ISO-8601 date string with a year within the inclusive range 0 through 9999 to the new Date() constructor or the ISODate() function. These functions accept the following formats:

The listed options state you can pass an integer to ISODate() in milliseconds since the UNIX Epoch (Jan 1st 1970)

With this info you could generate a random integer between whatever starting date in milliseconds and the current date in milliseconds and pass that to the ISODate() function upon document creation giving it a random date.
Note you'd need to generate a new random date for each document if you want them to be different.

Here is a working example in Node.js

```html
function getRandomTimestamp () {
  // 1577854800 is the timestamp for 2020-01-01 00:00:00
  const minDate = 1577854800
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (Date.now() - minDate) + minDate)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for doing it in MongoDB aggregation.